# Is there a known proof that $R(5,5)\leq 47$ in Ramsey theory?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

As an application to a model describing graphs with partial information, I found what might be an (as yet unverified) proof that $R(5,5)\leq 47$.

According to the Dynamic Survey of Ramsey Numbers at https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1
that bound is not yet proved.  However, I don't know if that survey is up to date.

Comment: The current best known upper bound is $48$. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08768v2).

Comment: The dynamic survey is up to date. An improvement as you indicate would certainly grant an update there.

Comment: Well, upon checking, I just found an error, but I think the proof is recoverable, with a little more work and time.

Comment: @Edwin, normally I don't suggest advertising proofs or proof attempts on MathOverflow. (Your reference request for an update seems fine to me.) In this case, if you have a write-up which indicates the error first and your idea for a fix, followed by a good write up, you might crowd source a solution by providing a link to the write up, either as a comment here or on your user page. Gerhard "In Case The Aliens Arrive" Paseman, 2019.09.18.